# Wrong "Open a Question" URL on Network Login Troubleshooting Page

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, design

The "If you're unable to fix the issues, please open a question on our meta discussion site." link on the [Network Login Troubleshooting](https://stackoverflow.com/network-login-help/) page does not work.

It doesn't work because there are two `http://` in the link. And at least Chrome turns that into `http://http//meta.stackoverflow.com/` if you click on it.

That's the href from the site source:

```
<a href="http://http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=chat&title=Network%20login%failing">our meta discussion site</a>.
```

Maybe someone could fix that.

---

PS: If you don't see this link, you are not having problems with the log in ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this.

Fixed in the next build (rev 2013.9.26.1037).